# Why isn't this bulk mysql case statement working?

Tags: mysql, case

```
UPDATE campaigns.list_name_counter SET counter = CASE WHEN name = 'occupant' THEN '2' WHEN name = 'occupant' THEN '3' WHEN name = 'Resident' THEN '3' WHEN name = 'Resident' THEN '4' WHEN name = 'Resident' THEN '5' END WHERE name IN ('occupant', 'occupant', 'Resident', 'Resident', 'Resident');
```

This table only has 3 columns. id, name, and counter. When it's done updating with the statement above, it only did the first occupant and the first Resident. It skipped the rest. If anything, if it only can do once per unique name, I would prefer it do the last of each, not the first of each, but anyway, should it update on each one, even if a name is repeated, or is that not allowed? and how can i make it update on the biggest counter number, not the smallest? Is my syntax messed up somewhere?

Comment: If you want it to update on the last true `WHEN THEN`; why even have the earlier ones? When should `name = 'Resident'` ever use 3 instead of 5? _Also, the term "bulk case" doesn't really make much sense._

Comment: What's the idea of having duplicate `WHEN` conditions?

Comment: well it's hard to explain but it's just how my loop works and collects all the rows of a csv file. when all names are unique i can make that work. actually even if there are duplicates i can make it work if the name is not saved in table yet, but once name is saved, that's when duplicates mess it up and don't act right. i need to extract current counter then save counter number with correct number after all loops are done. so if occupant exists and it's 1 and 2 more are in next csv then it should be 3 and if resident exists counter is 2 and 3 more are in next list then it should end up with 5.

Comment: maybe i need to switch to regular bulk update statements and not do case statements. by bulk i mean i gather up all the inserts or updates then execute at the end.

Answer (score 0):

CASE statements do not "fall through" like they do in C; only the first match will be used; they are equivalent to "if...else if....else if...else if...."